# Sliding / following navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a simple jQuery or Javascript solution to make a navigation sidebar smoothly following the user when he scrolls down a page.
Something like here: http://ucon-acrobatics.com/shop/

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the top position:

```
offset_top = $("#menu").offset().top     // absolute
position_top = $("#menu").position().top // relative to parent
```

Then create an event:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= offset_top) {
    $("#menu").css("top", $(this).scrollTop() - position_top);
  }
});
```

See also my example: http://jsfiddle.net/elektronikLexikon/LaVmG/

or change to `animate` link in the 2nd version: http://jsfiddle.net/elektronikLexikon/LaVmG/2/

Comment: thanks man for taking your time. I didn't know about the window.scrollTop() property, your second example nails it :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `position:fixed` on the nav, this has the advantages of not being so laggy.

You might decide to use `position:absolute` until the user has scrolled past a certain point before moving to `position:fixed`.

Comment: yeah I forgot to mention I wanted to use javascript to make it look smother. position:fixed just didn't do it in this case, aesthetically

Comment: The source to their page is here: http://ucon-acrobatics.com/shop/js/jquery/gui_reposition.js